# Training neural network with likelihood function

Tags: r, neural-network, backpropagation, mle

I want to train a neural network with likelihood function instead of typical squared error, I wrote some code in **Rstudio** with these characteristics:

- Neural network has no hidden unit (this is just for simplicity), with a single input and a single output unit.
- It is used to learn a simple linear equation (y=a+bx)
- I suppose the data have normal distribution (so I can recognize the likelihood function).

The codes are as follow:

```
# This code implements the basic backpropagation of  
# error learning algorithm. The network has not hidden  
# neurons and just a linear output neuron.  
# The purpose is to estimate a and b in linear equation y=a+bx
# and also to estimate the variance component of residuals 

#------LOAD DATA------------------------

x=rnorm(100,0,1)
y=10-3*x

#user specified values
Size=1
Lrate=0.001
epochs = 1000

#read how many patterns
n = length(x)

# ---------- set weights ---------------

#set initial random weights
# b is coeficient, a is constant and s is variance
weight = runif(3)
a=weight[1]
b=weight[2]
s=var(x)


#--- Learning Starts Here! ---------


#  Errors vectors
err=numeric(0)
L=numeric(0)

# do a number of epochs
for (iter in 1:epochs){

# --- calculate derivatives of -2*log(likelihood) with respect to a,b and s 

  Da=-2*sum((y-a-b*x)/s)
  Db=-2*sum(x*(y-a-b*x)/s)
  Ds=-2*(sum((y-a-b*x)^2)/(2*s^2)-n/(2*s))

 # adjust weights
  a=a-Lrate*Da
  b=b-Lrate*Db
  s=s-Lrate*Ds

  #calculate overall network error at end of each epoch
  pred = a+b*x
  error = pred-y
  err[iter] = (sum(error^2))^0.5
  L[iter]=-2*(s^(-n/2)-1/(2*s)*sum((y-b*x-a)^2))

  #stop if error is small

  if (err[iter] < 0.00001) {
    cat('converged at epoch:',iter)
    break 
  }


  if (abs(L[iter]) < 0.00001) {
    cat('converged at epoch:',iter,"L=",L[iter])
    break
  }

}

#-----FINISHED--------- 

#display actual,predicted & error
plot(err,type="b")
plot(L,type="b")
cat('state after',iter,"\n")
# res=cbind(y,pred,pred-y)
plot(x,y)
lines(x,pred,col="red")
cat("min Error:",min(err),"\n")
cat("a=",a,"b=",b,"Sigma2=",s,"\n")
```

It works, But I have some questions:

- Is this algorithm correct?
- As I know the variance component (showed by s) is the variance of residuals (here, prediction minus y). But they are not the same here, what is my mistake?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with RStudio. You could have written the code in RGui, Notepad, Vi, emacs, or any other editor. Save the RStudio tag for questions about that particular IDE.

Comment: Also, lines of code like `rm(list = ls())` should not be included in questions unless absolutely necessary - you wouldn't want someone inadvertently running that line.

Comment: Sorry...I forgot to remove it after copying. I've removed that code ...